# What's the best way to support monad transformers, in functions that take monadic commands as arguments?

Tags: haskell, typeclass, monad-transformers

Let's say I have a computation

```
class A  where
    foo ::  () ->  ()

instance A IO where
    foo x = do
        print "prefix"
        x
        print "suffix"
```

Now, suppose I want to write

```
instance A  => A (MyMonadTransformerT γ )
```

Then, in implementing `foo`, I'm forced to "unwrap" its argument, e.g. `foo x = lift (foo (unlift x))`. This `unlift` function can be bad for monadic computation. For a state transformer, it would be forced to forget any changes in the program's state.

It seems to work to create a more general method, which also takes a lifting function, and results in computation `t () -> t ()`, where `t` is the lifted (tranformed) monad.

```
class Monad  => A'  where
    foo' :: Monad t =>
        (forall z .  z -> t z) -- lifting function
        -> t ()
        -> t ()
    foo ::  () ->  ()
    foo = foo' id

instance A' IO where
    foo' lift x = do
        lift (print "prefix")
        x
        lift (print "suffix")

instance A'  => A' (StateT γ ) where
    foo' lift' x = foo' (lift' . lift) x

computation :: Num a => StateT a IO ()
computation = do
    foo (put 1 >> lift (print "middle"))
    v <- get
    lift $ print ("value", v)

run_computation :: Num a => IO a
run_computation = execStateT computation 0
```

*Question*. Is this the best way? Is there something more general one can write? CPS-style code? Thanks!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lifting a higher order function in Haskell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9243215/lifting-a-higher-order-function-in-haskell)

Comment: Yes, I think it's a duplicate. The "refying the class" approach I and luqui took seems to be the nicest though.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, forget that `class` business, it looks like you just want a function.

This problem is addressed by the `Monad*` classes: `MonadIO`, `MonadState`, etc.  So if you have a monadic computation which can do IO, but which is allowed to do other things, you would take as a type parameter `m` any monad which can perform IO actions:

```
foo :: (MonadIO m) => m () -> m ()
foo x = do
    liftIO $ putStrLn "prefix"
    x
    liftIO $ putStrLn "suffix"
```

Now it does not matter what `m` is, because `MonadIO` says how to lift it back to the operations you want.

The `Monad*` classes are somewhat non-modular in the face of new transformers -- the number of instances you need is quadratic in the number of monad transformers.  There are various suboptimal solutions to this problem.  If such things concern you, you can always reify the class:

```
foo :: (Monad m) => (forall a. IO a -> m a) -> m () -> m ()
foo lift x = do
    lift $ putStrLn "prefix"
    x
    lift $ putStrLn "suffix"
```

Whether to do this depends on your level of abstraction.  You will want the former if you are writing a library upon which to build content code, and perhaps the latter if you are writing a library upon which to build other library code.   It's kind of tricky either way though, all because monad stacks don't commute.

Comment: I haven't shown other instances of the class. So, yes, I'm sure, I want a class, but only for `foo'`, `foo` should be a function. Besides, the compiler won't be able to infer whether to use `lift` (1 monad transformer), `lift . lift` (2 monad transformers), etc. by itself.