# What is the purpose of contramap?

Tags: haskell

I read many articles about contramap and find https://hackage.haskell.org/package/contravariant-1.4.1/docs/Data-Functor-Contravariant.html#g:3 is the best.

Anyway I found, how to  use for example:

```
*Lib Data.Functor.Contravariant> a = Predicate (\x -> x > 20)
*Lib Data.Functor.Contravariant> :t contramap
contramap :: Contravariant f => (a -> b) -> f b -> f a
*Lib Data.Functor.Contravariant> :t contramap (\x -> x * 2)
contramap (\x -> x * 2) :: (Num b, Contravariant f) => f b -> f b
*Lib Data.Functor.Contravariant> :t contramap (\x -> x * 2) a
contramap (\x -> x * 2) a :: (Ord b, Num b) => Predicate b
*Lib Data.Functor.Contravariant> x = contramap (\x -> x * 2) a
*Lib Data.Functor.Contravariant> getPredicate x 45
True
```

But could not figure out, where it can be useful.

On the website, that I posted above, it says:

> Whereas in Haskell, one can think of a Functor as containing or
>   producing values, a contravariant functor is a functor that can be
>   thought of as consuming values.

Look at the definition of the functor:

```
class Functor (f :: * -> *) where
  fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

It consumes the value of type `a` and it produces the value of type `b`. On `contramap` it consumes the value.

```
class Contravariant (f :: * -> *) where
  contramap :: (a -> b) -> f b -> f a
```

Which variable type does it consume `a` or `b`?

Also a question from https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2016/11/covariance-contravariance about **POSITIVE AND NEGATIVE POSITION**. On the website it says:

- Positive position: the type variable is the
  result/output/range/codomain of the function
- Negative position: the type variable is the argument/input/domain of
  the function

Looking at contramap type definition:

```
contramap :: (a -> b) -> f b -> f a
```

Which type variable does the author point to?

Comment: You've misunderstood what the quoted portion is saying; but also it isn't really clear language, and you should simply avoid reading any explanation which begins with "one can think of...". That said, what it means is that "a Functor" (a value `x :: F A` for some `F` with `Functor F` and some `A`) can be thought of as a computation producing values of type `A`; and a contravariant functor can be thought of as consuming values of type `A`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A Functor `f` is thought of to 'contain' or 'produce' values in the sense that `f a` is like a container of `a` values. `fmap` allows you to transform the values held by `f`.
Examples:

- `[a]` 'contains' a non-negative number of values of type `a`
- `IO a` potentially does some IO and 'returns' or 'produces' a value of type `a`
- `(->) r a` 'contains' a value of type `a` for each value of `r`

Now a `Contravariant f` is something that can 'take in' or 'consume' values. `contramap` allows you to transform the thing `f a` takes before it consumes them.
The main example for this is usually using something like
`newtype Op r a = Op { runOp :: a -> r }`
(note the `Predicate` you used seems to just be `Op Bool`)
Now we have something that can 'consume' values of type a.(the analogy might make more sense for `Op (IO ())`)
Continuing this example of 'consumption' of values, consider `o = Op (\x -> putStrLn x) :: Op (IO ()) String`, now what if we want to make use of `o`, but for values of type `Show a => a`? well that's what `contramap` is for!
`contramap show o :: Show a => Op (IO ()) a`
(note that in this simple case `runOp (contramap show o)` is just `print`)

EDIT:
Another interesting thing to note about `Contravariant` is with regard to composing it.
Given `Contravariant c, Contravariant d, Functor f` and
`newtype Compose f g a = Compose { runCompose :: f (g a) }`
we have:

- `Compose f c` is also `Contravariant`
  `contramap f (Compose fca) = Compose $ fmap (contramap f) fca`
- `Compose c f` is also `Contravariant`
  `contramap f (Compose cfa) = Compose $ contramap (fmap f) cfa`
- `Compose c d` is actually a `Functor`
  `fmap f (Compose cda) = Compose $ contramap (contramap f) cda`

Comment: The definition of the data type has to be like  `Op { runOp :: a -> r }` not for example `contramap` on `Maybe a` does not make sense, because it produces a value right?

Comment: `Maybe a` can be thought of as a list of length 0 or 1, that is, it 'contains' 0 or 1 values of type `a`. You cannot define `contramap` for `Maybe` because if you did, you would have `phantom = contramap (const ()) . fmap (const ()) :: (Functor f, Contravariant f) => f a -> f b`, and that doesn't make sense since then we could convert any `a` to any `b` by using `fromJust . phantom . Just`. For an example of a `Functor` that is also `Contravariant`, there's `newtype Const c a = Const { getConst :: c }`, where the `fmap f = contramap f = Const . getConst`

Answer (score 5):

> Look at the definition of the functor:
>
> ```
> class Functor (f :: * -> *) where
>     fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
> ```
>
> It consumes the value of type `a` and it produces the value of type `b`.

This is not precise, and is the source of your confusion.

In particular, there are three distinct objects in the type of `fmap`: a function `a -> b`, a "functorial" value `f a`, and a "functorial" value `f b`, and whether `a` is consumed or produced varies across these objects, as does whether `b` is consumed or produced.

- A function of type `a -> b` consumes and `a` and produces a `b`. (This is the sentence you said, but with a new addition specifying *on which object* it applies.)
- If `f` is a `Functor`, then a value of type `f a` "produces" `a`s.
- If `f` is a `Functor`, then a value of type `f b` "produces" `b`s.

We can extend these observations to larger function types.

- If `f` is a `Functor`, then a function of type `f a -> f b` consumes `f a`s and produces `f b`s; and because functors are positive this in turn means that the function consumes `a`s and produces `b`s.
- If `f` is a `Functor`, then a function of type `(a -> b) -> f a -> f b` consumes an `a -> b` -- that is, in the implementation, we will produce `a`s to provide to the `a -> b` function and consume the `b`s that it returns! It does this to produce an `f a -> f b`, which consumes `a`s and produces `b`s.

N.B. the role of "consume" and "produce" alternates quite a lot in the above description, even within the single object that is called `fmap`; so saying "`fmap` consumes `a`s and produces `b`s" is not telling the whole story.

The following statement is also imprecise in a similar way:

> Whereas in Haskell, one can think of a `Functor` as containing or producing values, a contravariant functor is a functor that can be thought of as consuming values.

You have interpreted this to mean that `fmap` as a (function) object contains values, while `contramap` produces values. But this is not what was intended; instead, the statement was intended to be about the (contravariant) functorial values themselves, not the (contra)maps that are applied to them. A more precise statement is this one:

> Whereas in Haskell, one can think of a value of type `f a` (for which `f` is a `Functor`) as containing or producing `a` values, a contravariant functor `f` gives rise to values of type `f a` that can be thought of as consuming `a` values.

Regarding your question about positive and negative positions, you may enjoy [some of my previous discussion of this topic here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9243982/791604).

Answer (score 2):

First, look to the signatures, everything is there.

Second, if you want to "feel" the things, consider the functors and
try to verbalize what they do.

A functor does something with its contained type.
This can be a consumption or a production of things of this type.
A List, clearly "produces" instances of the type.
A Printer, clearly, "consumes" instances of the type.

When given a function, a producer builds a function which transforms the production "after". From a simple function, you can get a producer for the function domain in applying the function after the production.
The signature of fmap is "covariant".

When given a function, a consumer builds a function which transforms the consumption "before". Provided with a transformer function from int to string, a consumer, which already holds a consumer of string, will easily produce a consumer of int: by applying the function before consuming.
The signature of contramap is "contravariant".

We can say that the functions "transform", while the functors "consume" or "produce".