# Haskell MonadIO vs IO

Tags: haskell

What is the difference between the two:

```
recompile :: MonadIO m => Bool -> m Bool
recompile :: Bool -> IO Bool
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The types `forall m. MonadIO m => Bool -> m Bool` and `Bool -> IO Bool` are isomorphic:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
import Control.Monad.IO.Class

from :: (forall m. MonadIO m => Bool -> m Bool) -> (Bool -> IO Bool)
from act = act

to :: (Bool -> IO Bool) -> (forall m. MonadIO m => Bool -> m Bool)
to act = liftIO . act
```

[Not all types involving `IO` are isomorphic to a version that replaces `IO` with a constrained `m`, though.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9243215/791604)

Generally, one uses `MonadIO m` instead of `m ~ IO` when they feel like scattering `liftIO` through calling code will be annoying or when there are other `mtl`-style constraints needed on `m`; and uses `m ~ IO` instead of `MonadIO m` when going for simplicity of API (where `MonadIO m` contributes to complexity and therefore is not desirable) or when dealing with forking or exception handling (where `MonadIO m` is not possible for the reasons discussed in the linked question).

Comment: And an aside: the proof that `from (to act) = act` is easy. The proof that `to (from act)` is quite a bit trickier, and involves using parametricity to essentially observe that all fully-defined values of type `forall m. MonadIO m => Bool -> m Bool` are equal to `liftIO . foo` for some `foo`. (Yes, even `liftIO bar >> liftIO baz`, which is equal to `liftIO (bar >> baz)` by the `MonadIO` laws.)