# rewriting a monad with newtype in haskell - some clarifications

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads, state-monad

I have come across the code below and thought I wanted to rewrite it in order to get a firmer grasp of the Monad. As I have tried to do below. It raises several questions about aspects that I apparently haven't understood fully.

```
type R = Int
type W = String
type S = Double

newtype RWSP a = RWSP {runRWSP :: R -> S ->
                                    (a, W, S)}

instance Monad RWSP where
  return a = RWSP(\_ state -> (a, mempty, state))  
  m >>= f = RWSP(\r state -> 
    let (a, w, state') = runRWSP m r state
        (a', w', state'') = runRWSP (f a) r state' 
    in (a', w++w', state''))


instance Functor RWSP where
  fmap = liftM
instance Applicative RWSP where
  pure = return; (<*>) = ap
```

```
newtype CustomM a = CustomM {runCustomM :: a -> String}

instance Monad CustomM where
  return a = CustomM (\a -> mempty)
  m >>= f =  CustomM (\a -> 
             let str = runCustomM m
                 str' = runCustomM (f a)
             in (str' ++ str)) 


instance Functor CustomM where 
  fmap = liftM 
instance Applicative CustomM where 
  pure = return; (<*>) = ap
```

1a. Why is the runRWSP needed in the  original example after the let statement. Does this have to do with that a runRWSP takes a monad m, whereas the RWSP is a monad in itself with the type a which requires an anonymous function?

1b. In that case could one go about solving the original code by rewriting it so that no runRWSP was needed but rather a RWSP was used instead?

2a. What about the several nested tuples in the let expression.  Why are both important. The f a seems  to surround whatever the first runRWSP m r state returns and I guess we can only assume that this monad takes an r and an s due to its newtype definition, is that correctly? When I try to do something similar for the edited version I seem to get an error.

bc. Furthermore I suspect you can use the `m` as an argument for runRWSP due to the reverse nature of `newtype` like you would with: `ghci> CharList "tdada" CharList {getCharList = "tdada"} ghci> getCharList (CharList "something") "something"` at http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids#the-newtype-keyword

3a. Is it correct to say that the bind operator needs the runRWSP constructor on the right side, because the bind operator has as its output `m b`  which would require a function whereas the `RWSP a` is a monad and not a function and therefore does not change the  packed value `a` to `b`

4a. How can I rewrite the monad correctly such that it will compile correctly with the new data type?

Comment: This is far too broad; your "question" consists of at least 6 separate questions.

Comment: Ok i can rewrite it so that I shall focus only on 4a

Comment: The instances can be [derived](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/deriving_via.html#extension-DerivingVia) `newtype RWSP a = RWSP {runRWSP :: R -> S -> (a, S, W)} deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadFix, MonadReader R, MonadState S, MonadWriter W, MonadRWS R W S) via RWS R W S`. You just need to swap the order of `W` and `S`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is the `runRWSP` needed in the original example after the let statement.

It is one of the two available, canonical ways of unwrapping the `newtype` wrapper and accessing the chewy nougat inside. The other would be pattern matching; e.g. you could write

```
let (a, w, state') = case m of RWSP f -> f r state
```

instead. It would mean the same thing.

> Could one go about solving the original code by rewriting it so that no runRWSP was needed but rather a RWSP was used instead?

Yes. See above.

> What about the several nested tuples in the let expression. Why are both important?

There are no nested tuples in your code. This one:

```
    let (a, w, state') = runRWSP m r state
```

is important because:

```
        (a', w', state'') = runRWSP (f a) r state'
                                       ^    ^^^^^^
    in (a', w++w', state''))
            ^
```

This one:

```
        (a', w', state'') = runRWSP (f a) r state'
```

is important because:

```
    in (a', w++w', state''))
        ^^     ^^  ^^^^^^^
```

> The f a seems to surround whatever the first runRWSP m r state returns and I guess we can only assume that this monad takes an r and an s due to its newtype definition, is that correctly?

Sure. I don't love the exact phrasing, but I think what you intended to say here is correct.

> Is it correct to say that the bind operator needs the runRWSP constructor on the right side, because the bind operator has as its output `m b`  which would require a function whereas the `RWSP a` is a monad and not a function and therefore does not change the packed value `a` to `b`

No, for many reasons. `runRWSP` is not a constructor, and it's not needed on the right hand side as described in the first question. `m b` usually is not specialized to be a function type, even when `Monad m` is floating around in the context somewhere; moreover, in this instance declaration, the `m b` that appears in the class declaration has *already* been specialized to something that is not a function type (namely, `RWSP b`). `RWSP a` is not a monad; `RWSP` (with no application to `a`) together with its implementations of `fmap`, `return`, and `(>>=)` is a monad.

> How can I rewrite the monad correctly such that it will compile correctly with the new data type?

It cannot be done. Your type parameter appears in a negative position; in any correct `Monad` implementation, the type parameter appears only in positive positions.

Or, in less technical (but also less precise) terms: your data type consumes/accepts/absorbs values of its parameter type, whereas monadic values produce/provide/contain values of the parameter type.

Comment: Nice answer, so will it help if I formulate the newtype as `newtype CustomM a = CustomM {runCustomM :: String -> (a, String)}` because this one takes an argument S and produces a tupple with an additional 'contained' type a. Whereas my former newtype was expecting a 'contained' argument a. Is that what you mean by positive and negative positions respectively.

Comment: @Piskator Yes, that `CustomM` could support a `Monad` instance. (In fact, there are several distinct, lawful instances for isomorphic types in common use.) I explain positive/negative [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9243215/lifting-a-higher-order-function-in-haskell/9243982#9243982); start with the paragraph marked "Edit:".